# How do I create a extension method that uses a profile similar to using in C#

Tags: c#, methods

I am trying to create a method that looks like the following when used:

```
Dialog (var d = new MyDialog())
{
    d.DoSomethingToAVisibleDialogThatAppearedInTheDialog(); //Call
}
```

Like "using", it would handle the destructor, but I want to add more stuff to Dialog, which would handle my IDialog interface.

Comment: Could you explain your question better?

Comment: @Paulo, looks like he wants to add his own flavor of syntactic sugar to the language, like `using(...) { }` expands to a try/finally and handles disposing objects.

Comment: @Paulo, Anthony is right. I am used to doing stuff like this in C++, so C# still gets me on these very low level features. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could created a class like the following:

```
class DisposableWrapper<T> : where T : IDisposable {
    T _wrapped;
    private bool _disposed;
    public DisposableWrapper(T wrapped) {
        _wrapped = wrapped;
    }
    public T Item {
        get { return _wrapped; }
    }
    public ~DisposableWrapper()
    {
        Dispose(false);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    public void Dispose() {
        Dispose(true);
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed) return;
        if (disposing) {
            _disposed = true;             
            ((IDisposable)_wrapped).Dispose();
            // do extra stuff
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
using (var wrapper = new DisposableWrapper(new Dialog()) {
    Dialog d = wrapper.Item;
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: @marind - I fixed up your implementation of IDisposable.  There were a number issues that would cause problems.  I wrote up a blog article several years ago that sets out the pattern correctly.  If you follow the recipe in there, you are far less like to have issues: http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/stevehawley/archive/2006/09/21/10887.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`using` is a language feature, and specific to `IDisposable`.  It cannot be extended directly for different semantics.  What you're trying would basically be adding a new feature to the language, which is not possible.

The best option is typically to provide an action, ideally in a generic method with a `new()` constraint.

```
public static void Dialog<T>(Action<T> action) where T: IDialog, new()
{
    var d = new T();
    try
    {
        action(d);
    }
    finally
    {
       var idialog = d as IDialog;
       if (idialog != null)
       {
           idialog.Dispose(); // Or whatever IDialog method(s) you want
       }
    }
}
```

You could then do:

```
Dialog(d => d.DoSomethingToAVisibleDialogThatAppearedInTheDialog());
```

Comment: Though, I like this direction, it really doesn't do what I am looking for. But I will be using it for other things.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up a class that does this called [ResourceReleaser<T>](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/stevehawley/archive/2009/06/26/using-lambda-and-raii.aspx).

Typical usage:

```
public class StreamPositionRestorer : ResourceReleaser<long>
{
    public StreamPositionRestorer(Stream s) : base(s.Position, x => s.Seek(x)) { }
}
```

the end result of this example is that when you do this:

```
using (var restorer = new StreamPositionRestorer(stm)) {
    // code that mucks with the stream all it wants...
}
// at this point the stream position has been returned to the original point
```